# replacing a placeholder tag in a string

Tags: c#, string

I am making a mail program where I would like to replace `**NAME**` with the name of the reciepient. I already tried this:

```
string mail = "hello **NAME**, how are you doing?";
mail.Replace("**NAME**", Reciepient.Name);
```

but it isn't working and just leaves the string untouched.

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: wait, is ** a special character?

Comment: because it changed name in the question to bold?

Comment: Yes  `**` is the bold delimiter in Markdown. Learn more: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: WTH ? Who is downvoting every answer here ?

Comment: Although it's not my downvotes, please check for duplicates before you answer. In this case, it's so obvious that there *must* be a duplicate around. The correct action is to close-vote (or flag) as duplicate, *not* to replicate the same answer across many many questions.

Comment: I wonder how people are still posting answers if this has already been locked as duplicate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Replace()` returns the string modified. You have to assigned it to `mail` or to a new variable.

```
string mail = "hello **NAME**, how are you doing?";
mail = mail.Replace("**NAME**", Reciepient.Name);
```

Comment: yes, this is it! thank you so much, can mark it as answer in 8 minutes

Answer (score -1):

use regex

```
    string mail = "hello **NAME**, how are you doing?";
    string pattern = @"\bNAME\b";
    string replace =  Reciepient.Name;
    string result = Regex.Replace(mail, pattern, replace);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

result : `hello **test**, how are you doing?`

Comment: This is not what was asked.

Comment: Counter example: `"Keep this - NAME - change that **NAME**"`: 1st `NAME` should be preserved intact; `string pattern = @"\*\*NAME\*\*";`

Comment: the stars can maintain the same and just replace the word `NAME` .. as I can see from his comment that he just wants to replace the `name` by the new value

Comment: just wondering why got downvote!

Comment: The downvote is because the question reads: `I would like to replace **NAME** with the name of the reciepient`... not "How do I replace the string between the tags".

Comment: but this line `string replace =  Reciepient.Name;` already shows how to replace so is  that not answering the question!

Comment: No? This line shows how to assign a string value of `Name` to another variable `replace`... clearly OPs problem is that he did not reassign the string back to the variable....